# Do I need a visa going to Amsterdam?

Tags: visas, amsterdam, filipino-citizens

I'm a Filipino living here in Italy. I want to go to Amsterdam but I didn't know if I need a new Visa. I want to know if my visa here in Italy is also valid for Amsterdam.

I'm a residence here in Italy for 4  years.I Want to go for a 5 day vacation in Amsterdam. I want to know if i need a Visa for Amsterdam

[image: this is my permesso di soggiorno]

Comment: Can you please give us a little more information on your visa in Italy? Welcome to TSE, we are happy to help but can not read minds.

Comment: Usually the visa or permit that entitles you to stay in Italy will also allow you to travel to the Netherlands, but there are some rare exceptions.

Comment: I'm voting to close as unclear until the OP reveals more info about their current visa.

Comment: I'm staying here in Italy for 4 years and I want to go for a 5 days vacation in Amsterdam . I just need to know if i need to get a Visa before going there

Comment: @R.decastro We can only know 100% if you upload a scan of your visa. But in 99% of cases, you do **not** Need a new visa

Comment: this is my permesso di sogiorno .. the thing that i upload yesterday was my visa here in italy

Comment: @R.decastro Saw both your scans. You **do not** Need a visa for Amsterdam

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is http://www.consilium.europa.eu/prado/en/ITA-HO-03003/image-118587.html

Comment: @Crazydre What? The user edited their question after I posted that.

Comment: Your residence permit allows you to visit any country in the Schengen area without need of an additional visa.  You are not supposed to be in other Schengen countries for more than 90 days in any 180-day period.

Comment: Thanks a lot  , can u suggest  a good place to go on Amsterdam . I'm going there for the first time with my friend .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Travel between Italy and the Netherlands (where Amsterdam is) is treated as a domestic trip - no border control, and usually both are covered by your visa/residence permit.

However, **very few** visas are LTV. If yours is it might not be valid for the Netherlands. Again, there are no border checks, so in practice, if you're not stopped inside the Netherlands, such a trip (while illegal) is possible.

Please upload a scan of your visa or residence permit (permesso di soggiorno) so we can say for sure. If you have a residence permit, you can go to the Netherlands 100%

UPDATE: you have a full residence permit, so you do **not** Need a visa for Amsterdam. When Boarding the flight, simply show your passport and residence permit if asked - though very often they only care about the Boarding pass

Comment: If you do upload that scan, please black out personal information as (most of) your name, the personal numbers and such.

Comment: If the traveler has already spent more than 90 or more of the last 180 days in other Schengen countries, the trip would also be illegal, but again the chance of being caught is almost nonexistent.

Comment: (+1) Beside LTV visas, another type of document that often does not allow for a trip to other Schengen countries are receipts for a first application for a residence permit as a refugee.